# Computational tree logic satisfiability.

Tags: logic, satisfiability

[image]

In the model I pasted above where $S_0$ and $S_1$ are starting states, is the $EXp$ formula satisfiable?

$$M,s\vDash EXp$$

Does it have to be satisfiable for all the starting states given the $M$, $s$? So to speak "There exists a next state in which the $p$ is satisfied" for both starting states or one of the states is enough, e.g. $S_0$ is satisfied while $S_1$ does not satisfy the formula. Is it the latter or the former?

Answer (score 0):

$M, s \vDash EXp$ does not make sense since $s$ is not a state in the model.

However, $M, S_0 \vDash EXp$ is the case. **Why?**

Let us review the semantics of the formula.

$EXp$ means that there should exist a **path** from $s_0$ s.t the successor of $s_0$ in the given path satisfies the formula $p$ which is only the case of $p$ is included in the set of atomic propositions in the successor state.

I.e $M, S_2 \vDash p$ and therefore $M, S_0 \vDash EXp$.

As one of the states satisfy the formula, it is satisfiable.

Refer to the semantics given [here](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/propm/papers/CTL.pdf) or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic)

Comment: Thank you for your help I understand why it is satisfiable in the S0. However I found the M,s notation where s is not a state in the model, but set of states s={s0, s1, s2}.

Comment: Okay, never really seen that before and it was not clear from your question :)

Comment: This notation is even used here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic#Semantics_of_CTL

Comment: Actually they let $\mathcal{M} = (S,\to,L)$ be a transition system, $s \in S$ a state and $\Phi$ a formula and define the satisfiability relation inductively on $\Phi$ with the notation $\mathcal{M},s \vDash \Phi$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what "define the satisfiability relation inductively on Φ" means, could you elaborate?

Comment: Structural induction is used to define the satisfiability relation for each "type" of formula i.e the structures define in the language of CTL. Just a way of saying that you need a rule for when each "type" of formula is satisfied.

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't really answer my question on how do I interpret the formula given a set of states.

Comment: As I was trying to say before, I have never seen the notation so I don't really know.